# How to put multiple canvas js animations on one page. (Createjs)

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I'm trying to put multiple js animations on one html page.  I've started my testing with just two animations.  I figured once I learn how to implement two, I can easily implement ten.

I'm using Flash CC to publish html5 canvas animations (which outputs a simple html file and a js file).   One animation is called "ship" and the other is called "car".  As it stands, only "ship" is appearing on screen.

Below is my code.  (Also there's a link for all the source files.) I'm no javascript/coding expert, but I am a troubleshooter/experimenter.  I've repositioned code, tried renaming variables, etc.  I'm pretty sure the big hangup is the createjs variable.  I see that the createjs variable isn't called anywhere else on the page... so i'm guessing that it's being used in the remote js script(s)?  I've commented out the *var createjs = createjs_car* because if it's not commented, no animation appears.

Anyhow, I'm looking for help to get two (or more) animations working on the same page.  Thanks in advance!

Want the source files?  Click here:
[Click here](http://www.clevermill.com/stackoverflow/multiple-js-animations-on-one-page.zip)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Multiple Canvas Animations on One Page</title>

<script>
 // change the default namespace for the CreateJS libraries:
 var createjs_ship = createjs_ship||{};
 var createjs = createjs_ship;
</script>
<!-- I've commented this out because if the commenting is removed, no animation shows up.
<script>
 // change the default namespace for the CreateJS libraries:
 var createjs_car = createjs_car||{};
 var createjs = createjs_car;
</script>-->
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/tweenjs-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/movieclip-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="ship.js"></script>
<script src="car.js"></script>

<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

function init_ship() {
 canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_ship");
 exportRoot = new libs_ship.ship();

 stage = new createjs_ship.Stage(canvas);
 stage.addChild(exportRoot);
 stage.update();

 createjs_ship.Ticker.setFPS(libs_ship.properties.fps);
 createjs_ship.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}
function init_car() {
 canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_car");
 exportRoot = new libs_car.car();

 stage = new createjs_car.Stage(canvas);
 stage.addChild(exportRoot);
 stage.update();

 createjs_car.Ticker.setFPS(libs_car.properties.fps);
 createjs_car.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="init_ship(); init_car();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4">
 <canvas id="canvas_ship" width="300" height="250" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas_car" width="300" height="250" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI I see 2 parallel blank canvases.

Can you confirm whether it's getting 2 canvases onscreen that's the issue or 2 animations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so I've got both playing together by:

- replacing references to *createjs_XXX* with *create_js* in both *car.js*, *ship.js* and the init function
- removing the associated variable instantiations
- combining init functions

please see below and a [codepen example here](http://codepen.io/Visualife/pen/GJapGa/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Multiple Canvas Animations on One Page</title>

    <script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.createjs.com/tweenjs-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.createjs.com/movieclip-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ship.js"></script>
    <script src="car.js"></script>

    <script>

        function init() {

            var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

            canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_ship");
            exportRoot = new libs_ship.ship();

            stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
            stage.addChild(exportRoot);
            stage.update();

            createjs.Ticker.setFPS(libs_ship.properties.fps);
            createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);


            canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_car");
            exportRoot = new libs_car.car();

            stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
            stage.addChild(exportRoot);
            stage.update();

            createjs.Ticker.setFPS(libs_car.properties.fps);
            createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
            }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4">
        <canvas id="canvas_ship" width="300" height="250" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas_car" width="300" height="250" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
(function (lib, img, cjs, ss) {

var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes


// library properties:
lib.properties = {
    width: 300,
    height: 250,
    fps: 24,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    manifest: []
};


// symbols:
(lib.ship_1 = function() {
    this.initialize();

    // Layer 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f("#0E586C").s().p("ArnDcQiHigAjkXIaeAAQh0Dbl1Dcg");
    this.shape.setTransform(85.1,113);

    this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_1.graphics.f("#C0D0D7").s().p("AnFGVQDllvjlm6IMoAAQDHGnjHGCg");
    this.shape_1.setTransform(101.6,40.5);

    this.addChild(this.shape_1,this.shape);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Container();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,170.3,135);


// stage content:
(lib.ship = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // Layer 2
    this.instance = new lib.ship_1();
    this.instance.setTransform(-4.9,107.5,1,1,0,0,0,85.2,67.5);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).to({x:390.1},128).wait(1));

    // Layer 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f("#9DC7D7").s().p("A3bIIIAAwPMAu2AAAIAAQPg");
    this.shape.setTransform(150,52);

    this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_1.graphics.f("#438896").s().p("A3bLaIAA2yMAu2AAAIAAWyg");
    this.shape_1.setTransform(150,177);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.shape_1},{t:this.shape}]}).wait(129));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(59.9,125,390.2,250);

})(libs_ship = libs_ship||{}, images_ship = images_ship||{}, createjs = createjs||{}, ss = ss||{});
var libs_ship, images_ship, createjs, ss;
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
(function (lib, img, cjs, ss) {

var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes

// library properties:
lib.properties = {
    width: 300,
    height: 250,
    fps: 24,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    manifest: []
};


// symbols:
(lib.ship = function() {
    this.initialize();

    // Layer 2
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f("#000000").s().p("AGgBwQgvguAAhCQAAhBAvgvQAvguBDAAQBCAAAuAuQAwAvAABBQAABCgwAuQguAwhCgBQhDABgvgwgAqCBwQgugugBhCQABhBAugvQAvguBCAAQBDAAAvAuQAuAvABBBQgBBCguAuQgvAwhDgBQhCABgvgwg");
    this.shape.setTransform(84.2,140);

    // Layer 1
    this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_1.graphics.f("#E58A2B").s().p("AtYDcQgwjHDUhZICqAAQBGiGAygRIJ+AAQBvAzA7B3IFoAxQBSBNASCPg");
    this.shape_1.setTransform(86.5,113);

    this.addChild(this.shape_1,this.shape);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Container();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(-0.1,91,173.3,65);


// stage content:
(lib.car = function(mode,startPosition,loop) {
    this.initialize(mode,startPosition,loop,{});

    // Layer 2
    this.instance = new lib.ship();
    this.instance.setTransform(-4.9,107.5,1,1,0,0,0,85.2,67.5);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.instance).to({x:390.1},128).wait(1));

    // Layer 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f("#A57F57").s().p("A3bIIIAAwPMAu2AAAIAAQPg");
    this.shape.setTransform(150,52);

    this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_1.graphics.f("#666666").s().p("A3bLaIAA2yMAu2AAAIAAWyg");
    this.shape_1.setTransform(150,177);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get({}).to({state:[{t:this.shape_1},{t:this.shape}]}).wait(129));

}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(59.7,125,390.3,250);

})(libs_car = libs_car||{}, images_car = images_car||{}, createjs = createjs||{}, ss = ss||{});
var libs_car, images_car, createjs, ss;
```

Comment: ps. if this doesn't work, can you upload your ship & car code so we can replicate the full process?

Comment: Thanks, Visualife.  I gave that a shot and it didn't work.  But as you've asked, I've added a link to the source files above.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @frogseatflies apologies on the delay - work calling.
I've updated the answer with a solution where both animations work together which is hopefully satusfactory.